# Inconsistencies in accessing auto index

Tags: rest, indexing, neo4j

I've been playing around with Neo4j auto indexing and I'm quite confused...

What I'm using:

- neo4j-community-1.8.M05
- ruby1.9.3p194

The following code is also at https://github.com/LouisSayers/Neo4jChallenges

My intention is to create nodes which have unique 'uuid' values (generated by me). To ensure that they are unique, my thinking was to check against an index, and if the uuid value already exists, then I'd generate a new uuid value.

What I see is that for one of my uuids ('blahblahuuid') this works, but for the other it doesn't... and I don't know why (check in the Neo4j Monitoring tool console).

If you try the code below on a clean install of neo4j on ruby1.9.3 (no changes to properties etc) then hopefully you'll see the behaviour that I'm seeing!

Here's my code:

Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
source "http://gems.rubyforge.org"
source "http://gemcutter.org"

#gem install bundler -v 1.2.0.pre --pre

ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'bundler', '1.2.0.pre'
gem 'neography', :git => 'https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography'
```

test.rb:

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'securerandom'
Bundler.setup(:default)

require 'neography'

$neo = Neography::Rest.new("http://localhost:7474")
$neo.create_node_index("node_auto_index")
$neo.set_node_auto_index_status(true)

$neo.execute_script("g.clear()")

def generate_uuid(deviceUUID)
  uuid = Digest::SHA1.base64digest deviceUUID
  existing_node_with_uuid = $neo.get_node_auto_index('uuid', uuid)

  until existing_node_with_uuid.nil?
    uuid = Digest::SHA1.base64digest (deviceUUID.to_s + SecureRandom.base64(8))
    existing_node_with_uuid = $neo.get_node_auto_index('uuid', uuid)
  end
  uuid
end


def generate_node(deviceUUID)
  uuid = generate_uuid(deviceUUID)
  secret = SecureRandom.base64(256)
  currentTime = DateTime.now

  $neo.create_node("uuid" => uuid, "deviceUUID" => deviceUUID,
                   "secret" => secret, "currentTime" => currentTime)
end

generate_node('blahblahuuid')
generate_node('blahblahuuid')
generate_node('4edb096b479588f6')
generate_node('4edb096b479588f6')
```

To run the code:

```
ruby test.rb
```

Listing results in the neo4j console:

```
start all = node(*)
return all;
```

# UPDATE

I figured out what was going wrong - firstly I didn't index uuid properly, I needed to add:
$neo.add_node_auto_index_property("uuid")

and as Max pointed out, I had a '/' in my uuid.

Also as pointed out by Russell Duhon (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/neo4j/KyW0s5p5-fM)

I should have just used a uuid library - which is what I'm doing now (using the uuid gem - https://github.com/assaf/uuid/) and then I avoid having to check whether the same uuid exists - as the uuid should be unique.

I am also encoding all of my parameters that I pass through neography - as there is a chance that some of them may contain slashes, and '?&=' symbols which could interfere with the rest url!

Thank you Max and Russell for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doing:

```
existing_node_with_uuid = $neo.get_node_auto_index('uuid', '7sZfZnCgz4sL/TkE4tPqb5+GgF0=')
```

Which is sending a get request to:

```
/db/data/index/node/node_auto_index/uuid/7sZfZnCgz4sL/TkE4tPqb5+GgF0=
```

I think that "/" is making a mess of things.

Comment: Cheers Max - I'll make sure I get rid of slashes and question marks. 
I wonder if neo4j's REST api unencodes the URI params? 

Would it make sense to encode URI params like this in neography before making the api call? I can imagine others tripping up on this over time - it could be a source for injection type attacks. 

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!!

Comment: Looks like neo4j doesn't unencode uri params before storing them

Comment: One more thing - 
Do you know why my code doesn't seem to pick up the auto indexing? I haven't worked it out - I modified neo4j.properties, to have 

node_auto_indexing=true 
and
node_keys_indexable=uuid

but the code above (with CGI URI encoding to fix the '/' issue) keeps producing nodes with the same uuid...

Comment: no worries - I needed to add $neo.add_node_auto_index_property("uuid") - looking through the neography specs helped :)